# Vimeo not working on iPad

Tags: ios, html, ipad, vimeo

I have a website with a Vimeo video on it. But it doesn't work on iPad. It doesn't display it and it appears invisible. This works fine on desktop and android, but doesn't seem to work on iPad.

I have used this code:

```
<object width="520" height="324"><param name="movie" value="http://vimeo.com/moogaloop.swf?clip_id=90321871"><param name="allowFullScreen" value="True"><param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"><embed src="http://vimeo.com/moogaloop.swf?clip_id=90321871" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="True" width="520" height="324"></object>
```

What is causing this ? Need Guidance.

Thanks.

Comment: ".swf" as in Flash...

Answer (score 1):

`<iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/90321871" width="520" height="324" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>`
should work fine.

The moogaloop player is [deprecated](http://vimeo.com/help/faq/sharing-videos/embedding-videos#what-is-the-old-embed-code).

[See the documentation](http://developer.vimeo.com/player/embedding) on how embeds work.